# How can I punch someone?

Tags: little-big-planet

I recently started playing Little Big Planet with two friends, one of them veteran in the game.

Occasionally he gives us a punch but refuse to tell how he does that.. will you help me punch him back? :-)

Tried tilting the controller while holding different buttons, so far no luck.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hold down R2 or L2 to move your hands, then pull in one direction, and quickly go to the other direction to slap.

Just make sure your friend is next to a cliff before doing it :)

Comment: Thanks, sounds good! You mean tilt the controller itself in one direction and go with the stick to the other direction?

Comment: @Shadow Nope, it's all in the stick.

Comment: @Ark OK will give it a try when I play next. :-)

Comment: You hold down R2 and and move the right stick to move the hand on the right as your character faces you (so actually your character's left hand), and you hold down L2 and move the left stick to move the hand on the left.